# Get Text of Link when Clicked in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is a sample of a URL that is in a site (project that I inherited).

When clicking on the link, I need to get the text "Click Link".

I have searched the web and all suggestions do not work.

Any help is appreciated.

```
 <a href="site/page" onclick="loadContent('https://site/page.com');">
   <span class="navitem">Click Link</span>
 </a>
```

The text in a span tag.

I've tried

```
$('. navitem').on('click', 'a', function() {
    var text = $(this).text();
});
```

But Console log says `$ not defined`.
I also tried

```
$('a').live('click', function() {
    window.location.href = $(this).closest('span').text();
});
```

Comment: Please show us your attempt.

Comment: I tried 

$('. navitem').on('click', 'a', function (){
   var text = $(this).text();
});

But Console log say $ not defined

I also tried

$('a').live('click',function(){
   window.location.href = $(this).closest('span').text();
});

Comment: Are you sure that you have imported a jquery library?

Comment: @Reporter
Yes
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.0.min.js">

Comment: And where is your custom JS code placed, in relation to the script element that loads jQuery ...?

Comment: @CBroe,
Directly after calling the jQuery script.

Comment: Unless it failed to load for some reason (have you checked the browser console(network panel for anything in that regard?), that does not appear to make sense. Please provide a proper [mre] of the issue when asking this kind of question, instead of just snippets that lack context and/or order.

Comment: Is jQuery something you've added or inherited? It seems a little pointless to have both inline JS _and_ jQuery. You should probably get rid of the inline JS and then make sure jQuery works properly, and is the latest version. And I suggest you read the jQuery documentation particularly the section on [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) which you'll probably find useful. @Gman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your following jQuery code:

```
$('.navitem').on('click', 'a', function() {
    var text = $(this).text();
});
```

you have deleget event on `a` of `navitem` which in your case is incorrect. It need to be something like `$('a').on('click', '.navitem')`. I have update this click event in following snippet.

```js
$('.navitem').off("click").on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var text = $(this).text();
  console.log(text);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="site/page" onclick="loadContent('https://site/page.com');">
  <span class="navitem">Click Link</span>
</a>
```

Similarly, when using [`live`](https://api.jquery.com/live/) method in your, second code you might get

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).live is not a function

this is because **the live API is deprecated has been removed since jQuery 1.9**

Answer (score 1):

```js
document.querySelector('a').addEventListener('click', function() {
    var text = this.querySelector('span').textContent
    
    // Do anything with text
    console.log(text)
})
```

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work.

Answer (score 1):

Your first code snippet contains two misstakes. Change this one by

```
$('.navitem').on('click', function ()
  {
      var text = $(this).text();
       window.location.href = text; //?? What eveer you want to do that 
  });
```

There was an unnessacry space between '.' and 'navitem'. Another one was in the on method. I removed the passed parameter 'a'.

Based on your last comment - underneath your question- you have to wrap this into

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
$('.navitem').on('click', function ()
  {
      var text = $(this).text();
       window.location.href = text; //?? What eveer you want to do that 
  }); 
});
```

Another point is your html code snippet. The presented code makes not sense:

```
<a href="site/page" onclick="loadContent('https://site/page.com');">
<span>...</span>
</a>
```

Your a tag overlaps you span tag and the href attribute overlaps the onclick attribute, so the value of href will be executed first. Your added code for span element won't be executed.